Удаления inline при нажатии
Нужна помощь,создаю телеграмм бота telebotAPI, как сделать чтобы при нажатии inline конпки удалились.Благодарю заранее за помощь
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def bot_message(message):
    if message.text == 'Магазин️':
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        l1_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('PUBG Mobile', callback_data='level1_1')
        l1_2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Brawl Stars', callback_data='level1_2')
        l1_3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Telegram Premium', callback_data='level1_3')
        l1_4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Roblox', callback_data='level1_4')
        l1_5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Пополнение Steam', callback_data='level1_5')
        markup.add(l1_1, l1_2, l1_3, l1_4, l1_5)
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, "https://photos.app.goo.gl/MyoDXDZXdVsjUtEB8",caption='Привет, {0.first_name}! Выбери услугу:'.format(message.from_user), reply_markup=markup)

        @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
        def bot_message(message):
            if message.text == 'Магазин️':
                markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
                l1_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('PUBG Mobile', callback_data='level1_1')
                l1_2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Brawl Stars', callback_data='level1_2')
                l1_3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Telegram Premium', callback_data='level1_3')
                l1_4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Roblox', callback_data='level1_4')
                l1_5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Пополнение Steam', callback_data='level1_5')
                markup.add(l1_1, l1_2, l1_3, l1_4, l1_5)
                bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, "https://photos.app.goo.gl/MyoDXDZXdVsjUtEB8",caption='Привет, {0.first_name}! Выбери услугу:'.format(message.from_user),reply_markup=markup)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def step2(call):
    if call.data == 'level1_1':
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        l1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('60UC - 100руб', callback_data='level1')
        l2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('325UC - 560', callback_data='level2')
        l3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('660UC - 1050', callback_data='level3')
        l4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('1800UC - 2480', callback_data='level4')
        l5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('3850UC - 4850руб', callback_data='level5')
        l6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Нaзад⏪', callback_data='level6')
        markup.add(l1, l2, l3, l4, l5,l6)
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Что вас интересует?'.format(call.message.from_user), reply_markup=markup)
        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id,text="Текст нашей кнопки", reply_markup=None)

    elif call.data == 'level6':
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        l1_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('PUBG Mobile', callback_data='level1_1')
        l1_2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Brawl Stars', callback_data='level1_2')
        l1_3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Telegram Premium', callback_data='level1_3')
        l1_4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Roblox', callback_data='level1_4')
        l1_5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Пополнение Steam', callback_data='level1_5')
        markup.add(l1_1, l1_2, l1_3, l1_4, l1_5)
        bot.send_photo(call.message.chat.id, "https://photos.app.goo.gl/MyoDXDZXdVsjUtEB8",caption='Привет, {0.first_name}! Выбери услугу:'.format(call.message.from_user), reply_markup=markup)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)


Как я понял вам нужно это -> тоже самое но при отправке сообщения
Но лучше используйте библиотеку aiogram по ней больше информации и она более продвинутая, и по функционалу, и работает быстрее

Насчёт скорости и функционала, я согласен, а вот про больше информации не сказал бы. Так, как использую обе библиотеки, то по опыту на aiogram значительно менее подробно описано. Во всяком случае о V3.
